# How to force text area to resize fxml

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I am currently working on a small application. I am currently working on the gui and I have everything layed out. It currently looks like this: [image]

I want the text area to fill the gray area below it. To be clear, I *do not* want it to resize with the content like all other questions here, just to fill the gray area. I cannot set a static size because the gui is sized based on the users display. All I want is for the text area to cover the gray box below it.

Here is the FXML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="code.matthew.todo.ControllerMain">
   <left>
      <ListView fx:id="todoList" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
               <Label fx:id="todoName" text="Name:" />
               <Label fx:id="todoDueBy" text="Due by:" />
               <TextArea fx:id="todoInfo" prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="100.0" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="newTodo" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newTODO" text="New" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="deleteTodo" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="closeApp" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Settings" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="menuAbout" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openAbout" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not answerable without knowing your scene structure. Everything we can tell you right now is: *"You need to use different parameters for the layout or change the ancestor layout(s)"*.

Comment: @fabian edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `VBox.vgrow` property of the `TextArea` to `ALWAYS`:

```xml
<TextArea fx:id="todoInfo" prefHeight="206.0" prefWidth="100.0" wrapText="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
```